# Contents are overlapping in fpdf Cell in php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have created simple file to export table data to pdf.
My php file Code:-

```
include("connection.php");

include('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();

$inc=1;
$r_type=$_GET['r_type'];

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);   
$pdf->AddPage();
$w = array(20,60,65,80,50,50);
$header=array('Sr.No', 'Name', 'Email', 'Property_Address','Property_Status','Property_Type');
for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
$pdf->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,'L');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('');
$real_sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `detail_view`") or die ("error :" . mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($real_sql) > 0)
{

    while($ra=mysql_fetch_assoc($real_sql)){

            $location= $ra['location'];
            $year_built= $ra['year_built'];
            $owner_name=$ra['owner_name'];
            $owner_no= $ra['owner_no'];
            $owner_email= $ra['owner_email'];
            $type=$ra['type'];
            $property_type=$ra['property_type'];
            $property_type2=str_replace('_',' ',$property_type);
            $sq_ft=$ra['sq_ft'];
            $bhk=$ra['bhk'];
            $price=$ra['price'];
            $post_date=$ra['post_date'];
            $reg_date=$ra['reg_date'];

        $pdf->Cell($w[0],6,$inc,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($w[1],6,$owner_name,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($w[2],6,$owner_email,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($w[3],6,$location,1,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($w[4],6,$type,1,'L'); 
        $pdf->Cell($w[5],6,$property_type2,1,'L'); 
        $pdf->Ln(); 

         $inc++;
    }
    //$pdf->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');


}
$pdf->Output(); 


?>
```

when I exporting pdf file the contents of table cells are overlapping on each other.when I used MultiCell the cells goes to next row .So,How can I wrap the contents in to that cell only??

Comment: can you post that file's screenshot?

Comment: did you try this `FPDF::MultiCell() method`?

Comment: ya but it goes to next line

Comment: obviously, it'll go to next line. because your string is way too long.

Comment: Check: [fpdf - Table with MultiCells](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this methods

```
CellFitScale()
CellFitScaleForce()
CellFitSpace()
CellFitSpaceForce()
```

for full description

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script62.php